# Lua string.format and use of newline or control characters

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm trying to string.format for raw output to the uart using NodeMCU.

I'm trying the function

```
uart.write(0,string.format("loop %03d local: %02d | gmt %02d:%02d:%02d local %02d/%02d/%04d\n",loops,timezonetime,gmthours,gmtmins,gmtsecs,Nmonth,Nday,Nyear))
```

but the \n is ignored, and text is concatenated.

```
print(string.format("loop %03d local: %02d | gmt %02d:%02d:%02d local %02d/%02d/%04d",loops,timezonetime,gmthours,gmtmins,gmtsecs,Nmonth,Nday,Nyear))
```

works as expected, but I can't control the newline always added by print()

How can I use uart.write and string.format to control the output including the placement and use of newline and other control characters?

Comment: Doesn't example from docs `uart.write(0, "Hello, world\n")` work for you?

Comment: Try `uart.write(0, "Hello, world\r\n")`

Answer (score 0):

The issue a result of newline handling in the LuaLoader that was used for accessing the NodeMCU board.  When used with PUTTY, the output is as expected.

Here are the results of more detailed testing. It appears that \r does not work in the string parameter passed to uart.write()

```
-- uart.write Test
print("______first test____________")   -- prime the output with a line and newline
uart.write(0,"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf")   -- no newline
print("______should be at end of same line as asdf...______") 
uart.write(0,"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(newline)\n")  -- with newline
print("______should be on line following asdf...____________")   
uart.write(0,"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(CR)\r")  -- with return only
uart.write(0,"OVERWRITE\n")  -- overwrite the first part of asdf line, then newline
print("______should be on newline below OVERWRITE line ____________")
```

Output results:

```
dofile("uwtest.lua")
______first test____________
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf______should be at end of same line as asdf...______
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(newline)
______should be on line following asdf...____________
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(CR)
OVERWRITE
______should be on newline below OVERWRITE line ____________
>
```

The expected result is the string "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(CR)\r"  will be followed by a CR but not LF, causing the terminal cursor to move to the left

This appears to be an issue with the terminal emulation in LuaLoader.

When I connect to the NodeMCU with Putty, I get this output:

```
> dofile("uwtest.lua")
______first test____________
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf______should be at end of same line as asdf...______
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf(newline)
                             ______should be on line following asdf...____________
OVERWRITEsdfasdfasdf(CR)
         ______should be on newline below OVERWRITE line ____________
>
```

The Putty output is as expected.